# Uma dúvida sobre o Google SEO

Tags: seo, google

Gostaria de tirar algumas dúvidas sobre como o website é mostrado na pesquisa do Google

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
meusite.com.br/produtos?tipo=camisa
meusite.com.br/produtos?tipo=chinelo
meusite.com.br/produtos?tipo=roupa
```

Quando alguém for pesquisar algo sobre isso no meu site no Google, vai aparecer a camisa, o chinelo e a roupa? Ou eu preciso criar uma página separadamente para cada um sem ter que usar parâmetros na *URL* para aparecer?

Comment: O Google não se baseia apena na URL para gerar os resultados da busca.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Um site bem estruturado com SEO, será mostrado de acordo com a "palavra  chave" digitada no campo de pesquisa no site Google.
Se for pesquisado o termo "comprar roupas" ou roupas baratas, por exemplo será mostrado a página que está escrito roupa em sua url.
Você pode otimizar cada pagina individualmente e colocar palavras chaves diferentes da url, exemplo: usuário pode pesquisar por "calça jeans" e o Google direcionar para sua url `meusite.com.br/produtos?tipo=roupa`.
Porém tem uma série de fatores que influenciam numa pesquisa, uma das mais importantes são os links patrocinados, que funciona na mesma lógica explicada acima, também conhecido como [Google Adwords](https://adwords.google.com/intl/pt-BR_br/home/) e tem um custo gerenciável.
Dependendo da plataforma ecommerce que é usada para vender seu produtos, você encontra vários plugins de otimização para suas páginas e produtos.
O Google também disponibiliza várias ferramentas para otimização do seu site.
Alguns link:
[PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)
, [GoogleWebMaster](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=pt-BR),
[Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/),
[Schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_why).
Tem muito mais, vale a pena estudar cada uma delas...
Vale a pena ressaltar também que um bom sistema SEO funciona bem desde que o site seja responsivo, ou seja, possua versão para mobiles e tablets.